# PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync hangs app forever

Tags: windows, azure, push-notification, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have gone through many tutorials to get the method below working but when it is executed, the app hangs forever because the method never finishes.

```
PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync
```

The method does not throw any exceptions and I cant debug the cause either, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so please correct me on my code and app capabilities. Thanks.

Notification Initialization Method:

```
private async Task InitNotificationsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        Constants.NotificationChannel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
        Constants.NotifyHub = new NotificationHub("hub name", "access key");
        Constants.NotificationHubRegistration = await Constants.NotifyHub.RegisterNativeAsync(Constants.NotificationChannel.Uri);
        if (!(Constants.NotificationHubRegistration != null) || !(Constants.NotificationHubRegistration.RegistrationId != null)) await new MessageDialog("Microsoft Azure Push Notification Services are unavailable!", "Problem!?").ShowAsync();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        await new MessageDialog("Microsoft Azure Push Notification Services are unavailable!\n\n" + e.Message, "Problem!?").ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

App Capabilities:

- Internet (Client & Server)
- Internet (Client)
- Location
- User Account Information

Comment: I can't find any problem in your code snippet, where did you call this task `InitNotificationsAsync()`?

Comment: I call it in my custom splash screen in a 'internal static Task Begin()' method @GraceFeng-MSFT

Comment: After some research I have found that it does this randomly after testing my app for a while. I also learnt that stopping all Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost processes and uninstalling the app or just simply restarting your computer stop the currently in process connection to the Push Notification service. @GraceFeng-MSFT